# Node.js application : proper deployment and security

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a fairly simple chat app written in node.js which does not use a database. The application implement socket.io and consists of two code files, one being the client side with the JQuery,html,css, and node logic and the other file is the server file. The way I have it working is all users get assigned a socket object with their username attached to it as a property. The socket objects are then stored in a single array on the server side, my question is, when I deploy the application and the user executes my code will the server side code be running locally on their machine? and if this is so then does that mean my application will not work because then obviously only they would be in the array. Basically I'm asking would this approach work for a real-time network application

Comment: also does it matter that the client can see the node.js part of the code when they hit "view source" for example they can see the socket event handlers and what not, would they be able to say copy and paste the code into an editor, save it then re-run it in their browser and still connect to my server?

Answer (score 1):

`will the server side code be running locally on their machine?`

NO.

`Basically I'm asking would this approach work for a real-time network application`

You can test it very easy by connecting 2 different browsers (or the same browser in normal + in private mode) to the server and see if you can chat between them. If this test succeeds, then the answer to your question is YES.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I have one more question, does it matter that the client can see the node.js part of the code when they hit "view source" for example they can see the socket event handlers and what not, would they be able to say copy and paste the code into an editor, save it then re-run it in their browser and still connect to my server?

Answer (score 0):

*when I deploy the application and the user executes my code will the server side code be running locally on their machine*

server side nodejs code won't be running locally on user's machine

As a side note, you might want to try [ChitChat](https://github.com/kyle-dorman/ChitChat.js) a similar open source project

Comment: Thank you and I will certainly look into ChitChat